# How to convert URL rewrite from Apache to Hiawatha

Tags: regex, hiawatha

I'm using the [Hiawatha webserver](http://www.hiawatha-webserver.org/) and need to convert the following Apache URL rewrite rule into a [URL toolkit](http://www.hiawatha-webserver.org/howto/url_toolkit) rule.

```
RewriteRule ^symphony\/api(\/(.*\/?))?$ extensions/rest_api/handler.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

`%{QUERY_STRING}` can't be used in Hiawatha's URL toolkit.

I've tried a few things, but my regex is poor.

Here's the basic Hiawatha URL rewrite format:

```
Match <originalurl> Rewrite <rewrittenurl>
```

An example URL that needs to be rewritten:

```
http://domain.co.uk/symphony/api/entries/photos/?auth-token=019ccc6e
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, try

```
Match ^symphony\/api(\/(.*\/?))?\?(.*)$ Rewrite extensions/rest_api/handler.php?url=$1&$2
Match ^symphony\/api(\/(.*\/?))?$ Rewrite extensions/rest_api/handler.php?url=$1
```

Comment: I found something similar on http://serverfault.com/questions/130866/clean-urls-on-hiawatha and adapted the solution a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Nils. That gives 'Page not found' and is rewritten to `/extensions/rest_api/handler.php?url=/entries/photos/&entries/photos/`

Comment: I just found that changing the $2 at the end of the first line to $3 seems to do the trick, and gives `/extensions/rest_api/handler.php?url=/entries/photos/&auth-token=xxxxxx`. The API still isn't working for me, but I think that's a different issue related to server config. Thanks!